# How to get React Native code coverage for integration tests?

Tags: react-native, integration-testing, appium, istanbul

I'm running React Native integration tests using Appium and Mocha.

My question is: is it possible to get a code coverage report from the integration tests?

Answer (score -2):

Android Code coverage is used for android with appium. please refer the link below
[android Code coverage](http://appium.io/slate/en/v1.0.0/?java#android-coverage)

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable.

Comment: The Android Code coverage will deliver java code coverage data but in react-native, what we are looking for is Javascript code coverage analysis